# Python filter list to remove certain links from html source code

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I have html source code which I want to filter out one or more links and keep the others.

I have set up my filter with "*" as the wildcard:

```
<a*>Link1</a>‚ <a*>Link2</a>‚ or <a*>Link3</a>
<a*>A bad link*</a>
some text* <a*>update*</a>
other text right before link <a*>click here</a>
```

I would like to filter out every instance of the link from the html source code using python. I'm ok with loading the list into an array.  I need some help with the filter.  Each line break would signify a separate filter and I only want to remove the link(s) and not the text

I am still very new to python and regex/beautifulsoup.  Even if you could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: so a bad link is if you just have <a>wqeqweq</a> in single line and nothing else?

Comment: You should be using an HTML parser, like HTMLParser or BeautifulSoup. HTML shouldn't be parsed with regex

Comment: I believe this link from a previous StackOverflow question is appropriate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 I agree with Ryan - use an HTML parser like BeautifulSoup.

Comment: @damir Yes, each line would be a separate filter and I only want to remove the link (<a>) and not the text

Comment: BeautifulSoup can be an option for me if regex isn't the right application

Comment: @Ryan then do it, BeautifulSoup is very simple and a lot of fun to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove `<a>` tags and keep only the text not contained within those tags:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs
>>> markup = """<a*>Link1</a> <a*>Link2</a> or <a*>Link3</a>
... <a*>A bad link*</a>
... some text* <a*>update*</a>
... other text right before link <a*>click here</a>"""
>>> soup = bs(markup)
>>> TAGS_TO_EXTRACT = ('a',)
>>> for tag in soup.findAll():
...   if tag.name in TAGS_TO_EXTRACT:
...     tag.extract()
...
>>> soup
  or

some text*
other text right before link
```

It's not clear to me if you want the text within the tags or not.  If you want the text contained within the tags do something like this instead:

```
>>> for tag in soup.findAll():
...   if tag.name in TAGS_TO_EXTRACT:
...     tag.replaceWith(tag.text)
...
>>> soup
Link1 Link2 or Link3
A bad link*
some text* update*
other text right before link click here
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsing it with the only purose of reassembling the whole document discarding just a part of the information would yield a lot of uneeded code.

So, I think this is better as a job for regular expressions. Python's regular expressions can have a callback function that allows one to customize the substitution string. In this case, it is a simple matter of creating a regexp that matches the "bad link", the text in between, and the end link mark-up, and preserves only the text in between.

```
import re

markup = """<a*>Link1</a>‚ <a*>Link2</a>‚ or <a*>Link3</a>
<a*>A bad link*</a>
some text* <a*>update*</a>
other text right before link <a*>click here</a>"""

filtered = re.sub (r"(\<a.*?>)(.*?)(\</a\s*\>)",lambda match: match.groups()[1] , markup)
```